# When to use obsolete or redundant when referring to something that is no longer required?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

I was sending a message to one of our developers internally referring to an element on a page querying whether it was needed or would be used but I paused when I realised that I wasn't entirely sure whether to use the word obsolete or redundant.

If we refer to the typical definitions:-

**Obsolete**: no longer produced or used; out of date.

**Redundant**: not or no longer needed or useful; superfluous.

I guess the use largely comes down to the context...

> So can you confirm now, is the dropdown now obsolete?

Is there a better use case for one over the other? Perhaps the bottom line, is it matters not which is used.

Comment: Then there are redundant systems that are indeed useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this scenario...

[Obsolete](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolete) would tend to refer to something that is no longer needed because the need no longer exists.

[Redundant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/redundant) would tend to refer to something that is no longer needed because something else is performing that function now.  The same need still exists, but something else is meeting it.

Answer (score 3):

***Obsolete*** would always suggest that the thing in question has either been superseded by something more up-to-date, or that there is no longer a need for it, because of some change in demand.

E.g. VHS recorders are *obsolete* (in both senses), as they have been superseded by other technology, and because the availability of TV on demand means that they are not needed as extensively as was once the case.

***Redundant*** suggests the thing in question is no longer needed in its present role. e.g. *Since we moved to a smaller house we have some  **redundant** furniture*. But *redundant* does not necessarily mean the thing is *obsolete*.

Answer (score 2):

In your case 'Redundant' would be a better choice, as the element on the page is may not be used or is not needed, ie, something extra in the page, something superfluous.

'Obsolete' may mean that there is something used on the page, but the software, library update has made is obsolete and now need to use a new and different method to get the same result as before.